# Pinout of metal halide lamp

Tags: identification, pinout, lighting

I've bought a few metal halide lamps (specifically Osram HCI-TC 70 W/830 WDL PB) and electronic ballasts for them to have really bright light in my room in winter (like [this guy](https://habr.com/ru/post/144514/)). The ballasts' lamp connections are labeled LL and LH for low and high-voltage, and the manufacturer's manual emphasizes the importance of connecting the lamps correctly, but the lamps themselves are not labeled anywhere and I couldn't find how to identify which pin is the high-voltage one (starter). Please help! The lamps look like this:

[image: bipin metal halide lamp]

Comment: New to me but if the higher termination is set to low voltage it may radiate less EMI but function the same otherwise. They tend to be noisy for mobiles

Comment: The diag seems to suggest LH is the high position rather than HV look for installation guide off OEM site

Comment: Is that a CDM-TC? It has no specified polarity. Insert it any way you want.

Comment: Beware of the ultraviolet radiation from metal halide lamps.